# Property "Any" is already defined. Use jaxb to resolve this conflict when using ApacheCXF

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, soap-client

Im tasked to consume a SOAP web service developed using .NET.

I handle the Java side of things so Im trying to convert their WSDL file:
www.mycompany.com/gamingservice.svc?wsdl
to Java classes using ApacheCXF or Axis1.

When using ApacheCXF, the Eclipse console logs error which says:
**WSDLToJava Error:**

```
www.mycompany.com/gamingservice.svc?xsd=xsd0 [0,0]: Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
 www.mycompany.com/gamingservice.svc?xsd=xsd0 [0,0]: The following location is relevant to the above error
 www.mycompany.com/gamingservice.svc?xsd=xsd0 [0,0]: Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
 www.mycompany.com/gamingservice.svc?xsd=xsd0 [0,0]: The following location is relevant to the above error
 www.mycompany.com/gamingservice.svc?xsd=xsd0 [0,0]: Property "Any" is already defined. Use &lt;jaxb:property> to resolve this conflict.
```

Looking at the suggested solution, I need to use jaxb and a “binding.xml” file.
My binding file looks something like:

```
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation=" www.mycompany.com/gamingservice.svc?xsd=xsd0">
        <jxb:bindings


            node="//xs:complexType[@name=RetrieveWeaponsForm]/xs:complexContent/xs:extension/xs:sequence/xs:element/xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:any[@namespace='http://tempuri.org/']">
            <jxb:property name="any2" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

Can someone point me at the right direction on how to do this properly? Im willing to read through docs and examples. Not sure if Im also asking the right questions. 
I feel like the webservice wasn't written properly as Im having problems (as stated above) generating Java stub classes or is this normal with complex WSDL files (where you need to use jaxb bindings)

The queer thing is that Axis1 was able to generate java classes but some methods are not working properly.